# How to Expand Tab Symbol \t with Spaces Correctly in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, ubuntu, tabs, usability

Situation: unable to find setting/one-liner to expand the tab symbol `\t` to four spaces and why strange additions of spaces in the code between `x 960` in Matlab

```
fprintf('Counter \t Free memory / GB \t Along... \t Image R \n');
fprintf('%6.0f \t %6.2f \t %6.2f \t %6.0f x %6.0f \n', ...
    counter, ...
    totalFree, perc, ...
    imageResolutionHeight, imageResolutionWidth);
```

Output where you see the tab size as a selection which does not consist of spaces

[image]

1. `\t` is not expanded with spaces
2. Matlab put spaces between `x` and the second figure (`960`) in `x960` although the code is just `%6.0f x %6.0f`

Fig. 1 No relevant in Preferences > Editor/Debugger > Tab where I have `Tab keys insert spaces` but it is not about expanding the tab symbol `\t`, Fig. 2 Nothing relevant in Preferences > Keyboard

[image]
[image]

System: Linux Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit
Matlab: 2016a
Documentation: [Editor/Debugger Preferences](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/about-editor-debugger-preferences.html), ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format specification `%6.0f x %6.0f` specifies that each number is a floating-point number with a field width of six digits, with zero digits after the decimal point. Therefore, since the number is only `960`, three spaces must be inserted in front of that number.

Have a look at the [documentation](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html), it's explained quite well.

`\t` is the ASCII code for tab, not four spaces. You might get four spaces in **an editor**, but in a string it's unambiguous, it's ASCII code point 9. The easiest and cleanest way is probably just to substitute the tab with four spaces directly in the string using [`regexprep`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html):

```
str = 'Counter \t Free memory / GB \t Along... \t Image R \n'
updatedString = regexprep(str, '\\t' , '    ');
```

By the way, I guess the format you want is:

```
fprintf('Counter \t Free memory / GB \t Along... \t Image R \n');
fprintf('%7.0f \t %16.2f \t %8.2f \t %3.0f x %i \n', numbers)
Counter      Free memory / GB    Along...    Image R 
      2                 19.05        0.19    960 x 960 
      3                 14.29        0.14    960 x 1920 
      4                 15.68        0.15    960 x 2880 
      5                  2.40        0.02    960 x 3840
```

Note that all numbers occupy the same amount of characters as the headers above. The easier way would of course be to store all the column names in a cell and count the number of characters in each cell to determine the length of the corresponding numbers.

**Or use [`table`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html)!**

Comment: Ok, table is not usable here because I am using the code inside a loop for real-time quality assurance. - - Matlab-table is only usable outside the loop, etc at the end of it where it is really useful!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using and/or replacing `\t` I would recommend to print the headline with defined format specification as well:

```
fprintf('% 8s% 24s% 16s% 16s\n', 'Counter', 'Free memory / GB' ...
    'Along...', 'Image R');
```

A preceding whitespace before the fieldwidth causes `fprintf` to fill in as much space characters as required to get the desired fieldwidth. This is documented in the [format spec documentation](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html#input_argument_formatspec) -> Optional Operators -> Flags.

Now use the same fieldwidths for printing the numbers.

```
fprintf('%8u%24.2f%16.2f%9u x %4u\n', ...
    counter, totalFree, perc, ...
    imageResolutionHeight, imageResolutionWidth);
```

Resulting output in my test:

```
 Counter        Free memory / GB        Along...         Image R
       1                   26.63           25.00      960 x  960
       2                   26.65           50.00      960 x 1920
       3                   26.33           75.00      960 x 2880
       4                   26.02          100.00      960 x 3840
```